# Can't install mod-wsgi-httpd on Windows 7 using pip (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, pip, wsgi

[image]

So, as I suppose, it's trying to use 'rm', but I'm not on an Unix environment (Obviously). How pip does not recognize that I'm under Windows? How can I install mod_wsgi **for windows** using pip? (Is it possible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_wsgi-httpd` does not support Windows. If you check the category specifier on [`pypi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi-httpd), you will find a list of supported OS.

```
Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X
Operating System :: POSIX :: BSD
Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux
Operating System :: POSIX :: SunOS/Solaris
```